# BreakOut game: Part of the stones constructor isn't updating

Tags: java

I currently work on a BreakOut game and I am almost finished. The only problem I currently have is that the color of the stones wont change, when hit by the ball.
The color of a stone is defined by its type (1-3) and whenever a stone is hit, its type is reduced by 1. I know a stone's type is succesfully reduced when hit, cause it disappears when the type turns into 0.

This is the constructor of the stones class:

```
public Stone(int type, Position pos) {
      this.pos = pos;
      this.type = type;
      switch(this.type) {
      case 1:
        value = 5;
        color = Color.LIGHT_GRAY;
        break;
      case 2:
        value = 10;
        color = Color.orange;
        break;
      case 3:
        value = 15;
        color = Color.green;
        break;
      }     
}
```

This is the method, which draws the stones:

```
private void drawStones(Graphics2D g2) {
    stones = view.getGame().getLevel().getStones();

    for (int i = 0; i < stones.length; i++) {
        for (int j = 0; j < stones[1].length; j++) {
            int x_position = (int) stones[i][j].getPosition().getX();
            int y_position = (int) stones[i][j].getPosition().getY();
            if(stones[i][j].getType() >= 1) {
                g2.setColor(stones[i][j].getColor());
                g2.fillRoundRect(x_position, y_position, 
                        (int) ((double)Constants.SCREEN_WIDTH/Constants.SQUARES_X)-2, 
                        (int) ((double)Constants.SCREEN_HEIGHT/Constants.SQUARES_Y)-2 ,1,1);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

And this is the method, which updates the stones type on hit:

```
private void updateStonesAndScore() {
    int posLine = ball.getHitStonePosition().getLine();
    int posColumn = ball.getHitStonePosition().getColumn();
    score = score + stones[posLine][posColumn].getValue();
    System.out.println(stones[posLine][posColumn].getType());
    stones[posLine][posColumn].setColor(stones[posLine][posColumn].getColor());
    stones[posLine][posColumn].setType(stones[posLine][posColumn].getType()-1);
}
```

Does anybody know why stones color doesn't change on hit, allthough its type is succesfully reduced?
Thanks in advance!

Comment: Put the whole code, so we can compile it our side and test it out.

Comment: @SamzSakerz: that "whole code" may be quite large and include *many* classes. Much better to request that the original poster create and post a [mcve], a small representational new program, one that compiles, runs, and that demonstrates the problem for us. This way, they work on isolating the problem in its smallest state (an exercise that often leads them to recognize the cause of the problem and create a solution), and we don't have to wade through yards of irrelevant code.

Comment: @HovercraftFullOfEels thats what I meant :P a working code that we can compile our side and test the error.

Comment: @SamzSakerz: then best to state what you mean from the get go. No sense in sending a relatively new poster to this site on fool's mission

Comment: well one thing one can say, if title  and the question in the last sentence are related: when you call setType, the constructor is not called - only the setType method. So the constructor is not involved when you call setType.

Comment: Did you change color when set new type (in setter)?

Comment: you are right, the full code includes several classes and unfortunately I am currently unable to create a small version of it. I ll just keep on trying myself and hope I ll find my mistake. Thank you for taking your time though

Comment: @Scoopa: we were able to guess at a solution, but if you decide to ask questions in the future, let's avoid this. Instead work on isolating your problem *before* coming here, and if still stuck, posting your [MCVE](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) with your question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You never change the color of the stone. It is set in the constructor but changed no where else (not in code you've shown).

I wouldn't even have the stone hold a color value, but instead let the drawing code decide what to color it, perhaps something like:

```
private void drawStones(Graphics2D g2) {
    stones = view.getGame().getLevel().getStones();

    for (int i = 0; i < stones.length; i++) {
        for (int j = 0; j < stones[1].length; j++) {
            int x_position = (int) stones[i][j].getPosition().getX();
            int y_position = (int) stones[i][j].getPosition().getY();
            if(stones[i][j].getType() >= 1) {

                // ********
                int type = stones[i][j].getType();
                Color color = .... set color based on type value here

                // *******

                g2.setColor(stones[i][j].getColor());
                g2.fillRoundRect(x_position, y_position, 
                        (int) ((double)Constants.SCREEN_WIDTH/Constants.SQUARES_X)-2, 
                        (int) ((double)Constants.SCREEN_HEIGHT/Constants.SQUARES_Y)-2 ,1,1);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: @kai: true, but it is foolish to use "parallel fields" as the OP is doing

Comment: @kai which is why the OP should post a valid [mcve]